# How to pause $http in angular?

Tags: angularjs

Hi I am using angularJS to my project and I use $http function to retrieve some data. but i want to hold other statements from executing until $http finishes. Any suggestions?

Comment: promise is your friend here. Google it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use .then() and place your rest of the codes there.

Ex:

```
$http(//your call here)
.then(function (contents) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(contents));
 });
```